# the bookmarklet doesn't work on the HTTPS website?

Tags: https, bookmarklet

Here's how I make develop a bookmarklet, get the input control value on web page ,
I write a javascript function, add the bookmarklet to my browser, load my test web page, is  test the bookmarklet, the result is ok, 
but then i test the bookmarklet on HTTPS website ,the bookmarklet can not  get the input control value, why?  the bookmarklet doesn't work on the HTTPS website?? Is there any way to make the bookmarklet work on https sites?

Answer (score 0):

3 questions :

- Why cant you get the input value : there is no reason why it does not work, almost certainly you are looking for the wrong id.
- Do bookmarklets work on HTTPS : absolutely, HTTPS is not the problem
- Can I make it work on https sites : if you provide a code sample, we might be able to tell you what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a pretty old question, but since I came across it while searching for a similar problem, I will add my thoughts.  If you wrote your own bookmarklet, this is most likely caused by your bookmarklet trying to access insecure content.  If you have other static content that your bookmarklet references on your own server, such as HTML, JS, CSS, or image files, the browser will block that content from loading.  This is because of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).  This question is also discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14367711/bookmarklet-on-https-page).  If you, or someone else viewing this is having the same problem, attempt to serve your content up as https or access only other content that is https.